# OnEdit(e) to be triggered by edits in multiple ranges

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that clears values in several named ranges if they're edited. I managed to configure OnEdit(e) trigger to fire when a single named range is edited but cannot figure out how to expand it to fire out when any of the ranges is edited.
I suppose that I can set several variables for the named ranges (e.g, MyRange2, MyRange3, etc.) but in this case, I`ll need to duplicate IF statement for each variable which I am trying to avoid.

I also tried to define myRange as an array but it looks like it contradicts with IF:
`var myRange = [ss.getRangeByName('total1), ss.getRangeByName('total2'), ss.getRangeByName('total3')];`

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var myRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('total1');
 
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();

  if (col >= myRange.getColumn() && col <= myRange.getLastColumn() && row >= myRange.getRow() && row <= myRange.getLastRow()) { 
        var name_arr = ['total1', 'total2', 'total3'];
        for (var name of name_arr) {
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var range = ss.getRangeByName(name).clearContent();
        }    ;
      } else {
        return;
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

- Make sure you take full advantage of the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events). You want to spend as less resources as possible and put all the absolute necessary code to be executed upon every edit before the main `if` condition that can end the execution of the code. For example `var myRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('total1')` does not need to be executed for every edit.
- I assume you want to run the script for a particular sheet. In my code, I used `Sheet1` and I added an `if` condition to check whether the sheet you edited is `Sheet1`. If you don't want this behaviour, remove this `if` condition and the enclosing brackets `if(as.getName()=="Sheet1")`. Then your code will automatically work for every sheet in the document (as soon as there are name ranges in this sheet that matches your criterion).
- Define a list of the names of the named ranges `["total1","total2","total3"]` and the script will iterate over all the named ranges and make sure to execute a block of code, only for these named ranges.
- If all the aforementioned `if` conditions evaluate to `true`, clear the content of the name range.

### Solution:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const arng = e.range; // // get active range
  const as = arng.getSheet(); // get active sheet
  if(as.getName()=="Sheet1"){
      const nranges = ["total1","total2","total3"]; // add here the names of the ranges
      //Let's get the row & column indexes of the active cell
      const namedRanges = as.getNamedRanges(); // get all named ranges
      const row = arng.getRow();
      const col = arng.getColumn();
      namedRanges.forEach(nr=>{
        if (nranges.includes(nr.getName())){
          let nrange = nr.getRange();
          if (col >= nrange.getColumn() && col <= nrange.getLastColumn() 
              && row >= nrange.getRow() && row <= nrange.getLastRow()) { 
               nrange.clearContent(); // clear the range of the named range
          }
        }
      });     
  }
}
```